# unable to install the asp.net core development certificate tool (dev-certs)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, docker-for-windows

Im new in ASP.NET core.

Im using: asp.net core 2.1 web api, visual studio community 2017 v15.8.9, windows 10, docker for windows community edition 18.06.1-ce-win73

So i developed web api with the above system, then try to run it with docker.

I have got this pop up error message from visual studio when i hit F5 from visual studio:

"unable to install the asp.net core development certificate tool (dev-certs)"

[See Error pop up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnsIB.png)

I tried to google it and also referred to this link below which asks us to update the VS to the latest version. I have done that but still got the error:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229417/mvp-unable-to-install-cert-tool-dev-certs.html

Could somebody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Docker: see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)

For other issues: open console -> **dotnet dev-certs https --trust** [ENTER] and **click on OK**,strong text that´s it